# don't have permission or doesn't exist

Tags: command-line, permissions, scripts, sudo, execute-command

I'm trying to configure an Oculus rift and I have a configuration script that needs to be executed:

```
GLADOS@deathbox:~/Desktop/OculusSDK/Tools/OculusConfigUtil$ ./OculusConfigUtil_i386
bash: ./OculusConfigUtil_i386: Permission denied
GLADOS@deathbox:~/Desktop/OculusSDK/Tools/OculusConfigUtil$ sudo ./OculusConfigUtil_i386
sudo: ./OculusConfigUtil_i386: command not found
```

Now I don't understand why it first says I don't have permission (when I execute without sudo) and then says that the command doesn't exist. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the script executable with:

```
chmod +x ./OculusConfigUtil_i386
```

Then run it with `./OculusConfigUtil_i386`.

Both errors result from the missing execute premissions.

Comment: Thank you will accept answer once I'm allowed to, by the way know how to fix that it now gives me a ./OculusConfigUtil_i386: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory error./OculusConfigUtil_i386: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libudev0:i386`

Comment: doesn't work E: Package 'libudev0:i386' has no installation candidate

Comment: Are you using 64 or 32 Bit? try `sudo apt-get install libudev0`.

Comment: 64 bits and that gives me E: Package 'libudev0' has no installation candidate

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you using? 14.04? `sudo apt-get update` before the installation.

Comment: 14.04 and no that doesn't work either still getting the same error after sudo apt-get update and then either one of the sudo apt-get install commands

Comment: There seems to be no libudev0 in 14.04, you should open a new question for this topic.

Comment: Alright I will do that then